# Listbox won't unfocus when selecting another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I populated an listbox component with a named range. The data spans 3 columns and it quite large so I need to expand the Listbox only when it has focus. The problem I'm running into is that the control never loses focus when I click on a cell. Why isn't it losing focus?

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_HasFocus()
ListBox1.Height = 300
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_LostFocus()
ListBox1.Height = 18.75
End Sub
```

Comment: `ListBox1_HasFocus` or `ListBox1_GotFocus` ?

Comment: Oh I feel so dumb. Thank you!